# ¿Cómo hacer un redireccionamiento de todas las rutas dentro de un dominio?

Tags: php, html, apache, servidor, .htaccess

Necesito poner una tienda en linea en mantenimiento, esta construida en php. 
¿Como ponerla en mantenimiento o redirigir todas las rutas internas (urls de productos) a una en especial (www.tienda.com/mantenimiento)? 
Actualmente el dominio www.tienda.com ya tiene redirección sin embargo si entro directo a un producto si se puede acceder

Answer (score -1):

Podrías hacer una regla en el dominio

```html
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://www.example.com/mantenimiento" [L,R,NE]
```